# Find-grep for List of .tex Files?

Tags: grep, find, regular-expression, editors, geany

My `document.tex` where I want to get the list of files, and grep those files with the term `gastric`

```
\subimport{}{1.2_protocal_answers.tex}
\subimport{}{2_protocol_answers.tex}
```

- `1.2_protocal_answers.tex` content: `this is a gastric juice lorem content`
- `2_protocol_answers.tex` content: `this is a second gastric\n test file`

My .pdf output is broken, but I need to search the contents in the material. My Directory is too massive to do it for all, which can be done with Geany's `Find in Files`. I would like to do dependent search on the files that are imported in the file. 
Attempts

- Pseudocode where I cannot get the list of files in the .tex document

  ```
  find ./document.tex -type f -exec \
      grep -E '\subimport{[A-Za-z1-9_-]*} {} \; 
  # TODO search the list of files with the word `gastric`
  ```
- Any IDE approach? My favorite IDE uses `grep` internally so I think `find-grep` approach is the most appropriate here.

System: Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit
Grep: grep (GNU grep) 2.25
Find: find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Linux kernel: 4.6

Comment: @Theophrastus As a one-liner, it could be run inside any IDE using `grep` as their internal machine. But I think you are right. It can be done in two steps. Please, consider an answer so I can better understand your proposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I use the search in directory by the script [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/789769/25388) with a redirection to Vim. It would be great to get something like that work in Geany IDE directly.

Answer (score 1):

Edited as the user needs:

```
   cat document.tex | cut -d'{' -f3 | cut -d'}' -f1 | while read file
         grep -i 'gastric' "$file" &>/dev/null && echo "$file contains gastric"
   done
```

Comment: I get blank output when running your command on `document.tex`. Those links are relative to `$PWD`. Should it be considered here too? Those two files are at `./` i.e. the same location where I run the command and where the `document.tex` locates. What do you get as an output?

Comment: I am understanding that you want to find files containing the grep rule, how document.tex is related with this ? And what you mean with this: # TODO search the list of files with the word `gastric`, grep -R 'gastric' will search all the files in the directory you are with the world 'gastric', i really not getting what you are trying to do. Can be more specific?

Comment: The document.tex's content is those two lines. Grep must first find those files, and then apply search in the content of the files in the list. I created the two dummy files in the body which have now the test content. I want to grep the content of the file list (here two dummy files).

Comment: Oh now i understand, i am righting your answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -l0 -ne 'print for /\\subimport\{\}\{(.*?)\}/g' file.tex
```

Would print the filenames inside those `\subimport{}{...}` functions NUL-delimited.

You can pipe that to `xargs -0 grep -l gastric --` to find which of those files contain `gastric`.

Comment: Great! I think this should be possible to integrate in Geany. I opened a ticket about it in Geany github here https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1081 for integration of such a function in the ide.